# Bamboo Issue - Clone & Modify

Tags: java, devops, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I would appreciate your help!
I have a project in bamboo that contains some "seeds". Every seed is basically a template build plan for some kind of project such as: Nodejs Server, Python application, etc.
I'm trying to create a program that clone one of the templates, changes parameters such as project name (because i want it to be on a different project) and plan name, etc.
Currently, i have come with just one way to do it, and ill save it from you, because its complicated and messy and not working that good in general.
I read about Bamboo Specs in Java but haven't found something that can help me in my situation.
So just to order things up: my target is to clone a specific bamboo build plan, change parameters and somehow to upload the new plan to Bamboo (to the correct project, according to the changed parameters), and all should be done completely automatic using a script.
Any advice would be much appreciated.
Tomer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at Bamboo Specs. You can use existing plans to generate Java code. Then you need to configure Maven project and use generated code. With some scripts you can change name of project and plan, modify other config and then upload new plan to Bamboo server by command line

```
mvn -Ppublish-specs
```

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-create-a-simple-plan-with-bamboo-java-specs-894743911.html for reference